# 12-hour Daytime Luggage Storage in San Juan, Puerto Rico?

Tags: luggage-storage, puerto-rico

My family and I will be returning to the states from Culebra, through San Juan.  We are going to shoot for the 6:30 a.m. ferry, which should allow us to make it back to San Juan by early afternoon in a taxi.

Our flight leaves San Juan just after midnight, so we'll spend the day poking around historical sites and museum, (recommendations?) and enjoying tasty foods.

My question is *what do we do with our luggage?*  We could carry it with us, but the day in S.J. would be a lot more fun without it.

Are there luggage storage services?  Does anyone know of a hotel that would let us rent a little storage, even if we aren't spending the night?  Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [at least one source](http://www.legendsofpr.com/airport_tips.htm) the airport has luggage storage, if you can get out there:

> If you have 6 hours in between flights, you may leave your luggage with
>   the luggage handlers association for a fee (787-791-3371) There
>   schedule is 7AM to 10PM. Look for the Storage Room sign located at the
>   second level near the hotel stairs

Alternatively, and I'd never have thought of a restaurant, but [Barrachina](http://www.barrachina.com/) - apparently the birthplace of the Piña Colada, has free luggage storage!

> Special service offer to all cruise passengers having late flight out
>   of San Juan.
>
> -Free luggage storage service offer from 9:00 am to 5:00 pm everyday.
>
> -Taxi stand one building away from us.
>
> -Free wireless service.

which seems to describe your situation perfectly!

Answer (score 2):

Bagsaway Luggage Storage is now available in Old San Juan, Puerto Rico. Visit: www.bagsaway.ca. They charge per hour to store your bags.